# border collapse and border bottom

Tags: html, css

Hi 
mine css class is as below for table records

```
table.tblBaseTblData{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    *margin-left:10px;
    *margin-left:0px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #003366;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table.tblBaseTblData th{
    font-family:Arial,Verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#003366;
    color:#F4EFEC;
    height:25px;
    margin:0px;
    border:1px solid #003366;
}

table.tblBaseTblData td{
    font-family:Arial,Verdana;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#000000;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;
    height:15px;
    border:1px solid #003366;
}


table.tblBaseTblData .oddRow{
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
}
table.tblBaseTblData .evenRow{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

when add additional css like below table border getting hidden

```
table>tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 280px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
table>tbody tr {
  height: auto;
}
table>thead tr {
  position:relative;
  top: 0px;/*expression(offsetParent.scrollTop); IE5+ only*/
}
```

what will be solution for this happens only in mozilla not in IE

Comment: Come on, nobody wants to read all that. Do some detective work on your own and narrow down the problem, then ask the question.

Comment: Why are you using hacks instead of IE conditional statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the section `table.tblBaseTblData` you have two different `margin-left`s. Take one out.